# Node js - Less css cannot find file to import

Tags: node.js, less

I have two Less files in the `public/stylesheets`.  I am using Express.js to serve them as CSS files.

The first file, `one.less` looks like this:

```
@import "another.less";

h1 {
    color: red;
}
```

The second file, `another.less` looks like this:

```
p {
    color: red;
}
```

When I try to load the page, the server quits with the error:

```
file 'another.less' wasn't found.
```

I have also tried an absolute path, but it didn't work.

This is my Express.js configuration:

```
app.configure(function(){
  app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');
  app.set('view engine', 'jade');
  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.compiler({ src: __dirname + '/public', enable: ['less'] }))
  app.use(app.router);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
});
```

Comment: Without knowing 'less', the error is about the file `another.less` not found, but you provide `another.css`, is that right?

Comment: Sorry, those are actually `.less` files.  I fixed it.  Thanks for catching that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Edit:
'@import "/public/stylesheets/two";'

Original proposal did not work.

Comment: If I use `.css`, it won't statically import the Less file (i.e. in the compiled CSS, there's a line `@import "another.css";`.  I want to combine the Less files at compile time.  Thanks for the idea, though!

Comment: Right. Try this one then `@import "/public/stylesheets/two";`

Comment: It worked!  Thanks!  Unfortunately, it will only re-compile if I update `one.less`.  If I only update `another.less`, it won't change.  Do you know any fix for this?

Comment: Not sure about that one, it would require digging into the less compiler probably. Finding out how it currently manages cancelling the cache and extending it.

Answer (score 3):

You should be using *connect-less* for this now. 
The original less compiler you're using above is a part of connect, actually, and if you check out the current issue list, you'll see that TJ opted to not support less any further in connect due to the compilers being too different (a case of "can't make everyone happy") :

https://github.com/senchalabs/connect/pull/174

You can look up connect-less here :
https://github.com/MartinodF/connect-less

I'll put the steps for install here, but understand they could become dated (check the github page if this doesn't work, and let me know and I'll sync up):

> Use NPM to install connect-less
>
> npm install connect-less
>
> Then load it in your app, specifying the source (and optionally destination) directory
>
> app.use(require('connect-less')({ src: __dirname + '/public/' }));

This worked flawlessly for me on an armv7/Trimslice linux box with expressjs 2.5.2 and node 6.6

Comment: Works for express 3 and node 10 too